# How to proceed to next file after first match - Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, match, pycharm

I am currently working with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os
import re
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()


def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Independent Auditors Report")
    with stdout2file("auditfeesexpenses.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html', recursive=True):
            with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f:
                contents = f.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
                for item in soup.findAll("ix:nonfraction"):
                    if re.match(".*AuditFeesExpenses", item['name']):
                        print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                        print(item['name'], end="| ")
                        print(item.get_text())
trade_spider()
```

What it does is the following:
- Open text file
- Search through all .html files in given directory
- if RegEx is matched -> print result to specified text file

In each html file there are up to *two strings* that contain my RegEx. This means sometimes I have *two results for each file*. What I want to do now, is to tell Python that it should **proceed** automatically to the next file **IF** the RegEx has found **ONE match** (No match is fine, as python is already automatically proceeding to the next file if it doesn't find a match).

So my results should have either no match (what if is fine) or ONE match and than proceed to next file without matching the second string with my RegEX.

Can anyone of you help me on this? Is there any short and elegant magic that I can insert into my code without altering it too much?

Any help appreciated!

P.S. I already searched through stackflow as the matching issue is a pretty popular question, however I couldn't find any question that would match my problem. If I missed some related questions on this topic, sorry for that and I would appreciate if you could post the relating link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `break` in the innermost `if`.

```
if re.match(".*AuditFeesExpenses", item['name']):
    print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
    print(item['name'], end="| ")
    print(item.get_text())
    break
```

Now the innermost `for` proceeds as long as there is no match. If there is a match it enters the `if` block and executing it once breaks out.

Comment if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think that it could be so easy. It works perfectly. Appreciate your help!